# How to receive multipart data from Angular in Nest.JS API application

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs, multipartform-data, multer

I'm trying to submit a small form including an image from an Angular project, and receiving it in a node.js API.

Here is my Angular code:

```
async save() {
    this.error = (!this.image || !this.email || !this.name);

    if(!this.error) {
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("image", this.image);
        form.append("email", this.email);
        form.append("name", this.name);
        await firstValueFrom(
            this.httpClient.post(`${environment.api_url}/emp`,
            form,
            {
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': environment.api_psk,
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
            }),
        )
            .then((res: any) => {
                this.empid = res.id;
                this.imageurl = res.url;
                this.page = 2;
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
                throw err;
            });
    }
    
}
```

I have confirmed that this.image, this.email, and this.name are all being received here successfully.

`this.image` is being populated via a (change) on the input field, with this:

```
async imageupload(target) {
    this.image = target.files[0];
}
```

The Node.js API uses NestJS. This is the controller:

```
@Post("emp")
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("image"))
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
async createEmpEntry(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @UploadedFiles() files: Express.Multer.File[],
) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(files);
    return undefined; // TBC
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the error on the API: "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found".
I've tried with and without the @UploadedFiles() decorator.

Any pointers, please?

Comment: What if you don't set the content-type header and let that get calculated automatically?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel you are a genius! I would never have thought of that! Thanks so much. If you add as a reply rather than comment, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Content-Type` header. The browser should automatically set the `Content-Type` *with* the boundary if it recognizes that there is a `multipart/form-data` request going on